having trouble in displaying user enteries from a database table onto a HTML table using springboot java application
this is my user entity class
package com.example.hardware_inventory.model;

public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String passwordHash;
    private String role;

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // getters and setters
}



this is my User Repository class
package com.example.hardware_inventory.repository;

import com.example.hardware_inventory.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserId(rs.getLong("user_id"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPasswordHash(rs.getString("password_hash"));
            user.setRole(rs.getString("role"));
            return user;
        }
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserRowMapper());
    }

    public Optional<User> findById(Long id) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id}, new UserRowMapper()));
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public Optional<User> findByUsername(String username) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{username}, new UserRowMapper()));
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getUsername(), user.getPasswordHash(), user.getRole());
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        String sql = "UPDATE users SET username = ?, password_hash = ?, role = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getUsername(), user.getPasswordHash(), user.getRole(), user.getUserId());
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, id);
    }
    public void resetPassword(Long id, String newPassword) {
        String sql = "UPDATE users SET password_hash = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, newPassword, id);
    }

    public void blockUser(Long id) {
        String sql = "UPDATE users SET role = 'blocked' WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, id);
    }
}


This is my User Service class
package com.example.hardware_inventory.service;

import com.example.hardware_inventory.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void resetPassword(Long id, String newPassword) {
        userRepository.resetPassword(id, newPassword);
    }

    public void blockUser(Long id) {
        userRepository.blockUser(id);
    }
}


I have users given role as user or admin and admin can add a new user in the web page
In the add user web page I need to have a list of users already in the table along with option for admin to add user and reset password and block users
this is my HTML code for the add_new_user page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add New User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>Add New User</h1>
    <form id="add-user-form">
        <input type="text" id="new-username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" id="new-password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <select id="role">
            <option value="user">User</option>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Add User</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="table-container">
    <h1>All Users</h1>
    <table id="users-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- Dynamic rows will be inserted here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


This is the javascript I've used
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const form = document.getElementById('add-user-form');
    const usersTable = document.getElementById('users-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    // Fetch users and display them
    fetch('/api/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(user => {
                addUserRow(user);
            });
        });

    // Handle form submission
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const newUsername = document.getElementById('new-username').value;
        const newPassword = document.getElementById('new-password').value;
        const role = document.getElementById('role').value;

        fetch('/api/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: newUsername,
                password: newPassword,
                role: role
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => {
            addUserRow(user);
            form.reset();
        });
    });

    function addUserRow(user) {
        const row = usersTable.insertRow();

        const cellId = row.insertCell(0);
        const cellUsername = row.insertCell(1);
        const cellRole = row.insertCell(2);
        const cellActions = row.insertCell(3);

        cellId.textContent = user.userId;
        cellUsername.textContent = user.username;
        cellRole.textContent = user.role;
        cellActions.innerHTML = `<form action="/api/users/delete/${user.userId}" method="post">
                                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                                 </form>`;
    }
});


My HTML is not getting populated and I'm struggling with this
My Database is already connected with my application I just can't fetch data correctly from my database

The User, UserService and UserRepository classes are looking fine. However, I think you are missing a controller class. Maybe you can try creating a controller class that exposes the necessary endpoints.
Since the service layer acts as an intermediary between the controller and repository layer, I suggest you update the UserService class with findAll() and save() methods.
UserController -> It should handle the HTTP requests and call the appropriate methods on the UserService.
UserService -> should contain the business logic. It should also call the UserRepository to interact with the database.
UserRepository -> It should directly interact with the database using JdbcTemplate.
Along with this, modify your JavaScript code to handle the errors in the fetch requests. Try to use Postman and check what the GET and POST requests are returning. This will help you to further debug the application.

thanks, I've added UserController class do you reocmmend I should use Thymeleaf templates?

It is better to use Thymeleaf templates only if you are familiar with them. While using the Thymeleaf template, you have to take care of the dependencies, configurations, model attributes, and more. Moreover, you should be able to set up a proper error handling and validation method too. So, it is completely up to you whether you need it in your project. Meanwhile, I recommend you to go for it, if and only if you are familiar with the Thymeleaf configurations.
Please upvote and accept my previous answer if it helped you!
